# What's the correct preposition before "row" (angry dispute)?

Tags: prepositions, present-continuous, present-simple

> I have a feel, the feel that I always experience when I fume in a
> row.

As you have read the sentence above, I doubt my construction is correct. It looks awkward. Hope you will tell me if there's something wrong with my sentence.

I have my confusion with two problems. Whether I should use present simple or present continuous (when I fume or when I'm fuming) and the use of the word **row** there. The word "row" I use means "angry dispute". I'm mixing this up with the idiom "in a row". That's why I'm asking which preposition is appropriate.

Comment: Did you mean 'have a feeling'?. The preposition is fine.

Comment: Yes, but I would say: to have a row.

Comment: I'd probably say "I have a feeling, the feeling I always experience when I fume during a row". But if you're having a feeling, you're fuming *and* you're having a row it seems a very emotional sentence!

Comment: That seems like a literary, unusual word.   So the meaning was clear to all, I would prefer "argument" or "dispute", not "row".  (us english).

Comment: @Sam raises a good point. If your audience is primarily BrE speakers, you're fine. Otherwise, it's time for a different word.

Comment: The sequence ***to fume in a row*** doesn't work well. Valid / natural alternatives include ***to get worked up / steamed up** [in a row / in a heated argument]*. Or even more "slangily", *He gets **exercised** in [vocal] disagreements*.